# Como hacer tabla datatable responsiva al agregar paneles a su izq o der?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, datatables, responsive

En el siguiente ejemplo en el JS creo una tabla basica datatable, creo de forma sencilla las funciones para abrir y cerrar los paneles y defino la data con la que se llenará la tabla por medio de una variable javascript.

En el CSS defino los estilos para los paneles izquierdo y derecho (sidebarLeft,sidebarRight), para que ocupen su posición en su respectivo lugar, les añado color y le añado estilo para la posición y el color de su boton cerrar (closebtnLeft, closebtnRight).

y por ultimo en el apartado de html solamente añado el div del panel izquierdo, el contenedor *main* que contiene la tabla que se verá en todo momento y finalmente el div del panel de cierre derecho.

*Como pueden observar al tener un tamaño de pantalla suficiente para que la tabla se muestre completa, y al precionar ya sea el boton del panel izquierdo o el boton del panel derecho, la tabla no se vuelve responsiva manteiendo su tamaño antes de añadir el panel*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ],
      "searching": false,
      "lengthChange": false,
      responsive:true
    } );
} );

function openNavLeft() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarLeft").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function openNavRight() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarRight").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
}

function closeNavLeft() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarLeft").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
function closeNavRight() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarRight").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
}



var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    
];
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebarLeft {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebarRight {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


.sidebarRight .closebtnRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.sidebarLeft .closebtnLeft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidebarLeft a,.sidebarRight a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebarLeft a:hover,.sidebarRight a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!--sidebar left-->
<div id="mySidebarLeft" class="sidebarLeft">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnLeft" onclick="closeNavLeft()">×</a>
</div>

<!--main card-->
<div id="main" class = "card bg-light">
                    <div class="pt-3">
                        <div class = "row pull-right">
                            <div class = "col-12 ">
                                <ul class = "flex-lg-row d-flex flex-column mb-0 p-0">
                                    <li class = "d-inline px-lg-1">
                                      <button class="btn fas fa-arrow-left openbtn" onclick="openNavLeft()">
                                        </button>
                                      <button class="btn fas fa-arrow-right openbtn" onclick="openNavRight()"> 
                                        </button> 
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "card-block px-3 pb-0">
                        <table id="example" class="table table-hover display responsive no-wrap" width="100%"></table>                    
                        </div>
                </div>
                
<!--sidebar right-->
<div id="mySidebarRight" class="sidebarRight">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnRight" onclick="closeNavRight()">×</a>
</div>



<!-------------------------------- CDN's css-------------------------------------->

<!-- Bootstrap & fontawesome css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
<!-- Datatable css -->
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.0/css/autoFill.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.5/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
<!-------------------------------- CDN's js-------------------------------------->
<!-- Boostrap & fontawesome js-->       
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Datatable js -->
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.0/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.5/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.0/js/dataTables.scroller.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aquel que no sepa, la solución fue recalcular la tabla despues de haber cambiado el tamaño, esto lo puedes hace con la propiedad "responsive.recalc()"
en este ejemplo lo añado de esta forma:

```
table.responsive.recalc()
```

```js
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ],
      "searching": false,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "responsive":true
    });
});

function recalc() {
  table.responsive.recalc();
}

function openNavLeft() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarLeft").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  recalc();
}

function openNavRight() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarRight").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
  recalc();
}

function closeNavLeft() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarLeft").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  recalc();
}
function closeNavRight() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebarRight").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
  recalc();
}



var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    
];
```

```css
.sidebarLeft {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebarRight {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebarRight .closebtnRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.sidebarLeft .closebtnLeft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidebarLeft a,
.sidebarRight a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebarLeft a:hover,
.sidebarRight a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!--sidebar left-->
<div id="mySidebarLeft" class="sidebarLeft">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnLeft" onclick="closeNavLeft()">×</a>
</div>

<!--main card-->
<div id="main" class="card bg-light">
  <div class="pt-3">
    <div class="row pull-right">
      <div class="col-12 ">
        <ul class="flex-lg-row d-flex flex-column mb-0 p-0">
          <li class="d-inline px-lg-1">
            <button class="btn fas fa-arrow-left openbtn" onclick="openNavLeft()">
                                        </button>
            <button class="btn fas fa-arrow-right openbtn" onclick="openNavRight()"> 
                                        </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block px-3 pb-0">
    <table id="example" class="table table-hover display responsive no-wrap" width="100%"></table>
  </div>
</div>

<!--sidebar right-->
<div id="mySidebarRight" class="sidebarRight">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtnRight" onclick="closeNavRight()">×</a>
</div>



<!-------------------------------- CDN's css-------------------------------------->

<!-- Bootstrap & fontawesome css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
<!-- Datatable css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.0/css/autoFill.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.5/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
<!-------------------------------- CDN's js-------------------------------------->
<!-- Boostrap & fontawesome js-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Datatable js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.3.0/js/dataTables.autoFill.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.5/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.0/js/dataTables.scroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```